# Removing double quotes from JSON.Simple JSON parser/writer for keys

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I would like to remove double-quotes from keys of JSONObjects (JSON.Simple) when converting the object to a String.

For example, I have the following JSONObject:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("foo", "bar");
System.out.println(object.toJSONString());
```

Which outputs:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

And I would like to remove the double quotes from the key object, `foo`:

```
{foo:"bar"}
```

Although this would not become valid JSON, how can I accomplish this? Should I be using regex for this case?

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to do this?

Comment: @PankajKatiyar linters usually complain about keys that are wrapped between double quotes.